# SQL - Major Account Exists Before Minor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am extremely new to SQL (using SQL Server Management Studio) and without a better understanding of terminology I'm afraid I am at a loss as to what to search to see if there may be an answer to this question somewhere. My issue is that account numbers are divided into two portions: major, and minor and there is a condition where the minor of "00" must exist before there can be a minor of "01" through "99" with the same major account. The hyphen between the account number is for illustration purposes.

- Major Account Number = 4 digits (1000)
- Minor Account Number = 2 digits (00)

**Example of correct account numbers**

- 1000-00
- 1000-01
- 1000-05

**Example of INCORRECT account numbers**

- 2000-00 (correct number)
- 2000-02 (correct number)
- 2001-01 (account cannot exist as the account "2001-00" does not exist)

There can be multiple iterations of a major account (1000) and multiple iterations of a minor account (00, 01, 02, 05), however, (2001-01) cannot exist if (2001-00) does not.

The resolution I am looking for is to output a result of "2001-01" as that account cannot exist until the account "2001-00" does not exist.

If there are any questions I will do my best to answer them. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that there are invalid answers and you're trying to clean them up?  Or do you want to make sure it doesn't acquire bad answers?

Comment: Hi Cindy - Sorry for the delay. The answer is both. Sometimes there are invalid answers and we need to clean them up and sometimes i want to prevent invalid information from being entered. I'd like to get to the point where we prevent from entering in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Account_Num TABLE
  (
     id             INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     account_number VARCHAR(10)
  )

INSERT INTO @Account_Num
VALUES      ('1000-00'),
            ('1000-01'),
            ('1000-05'),
            ('2000-00'),
            ('2000-02'),
            ('2001-01')

SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       CASE
         WHEN T.ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 'VALID NUMBER'
         ELSE 'INVALID NUMBER'
       END AS ACCOUNT_STATUS
FROM   @Account_Num A
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 B.account_number
                    FROM   @Account_Num B
                    WHERE  LEFT(A.account_number, 4) = LEFT(B.account_number, 4)
                           AND RIGHT(B.account_number, 2) = '00')T
```